# SQL Server 2008 - Import part of XML File

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, tags

I've been importing a whole XML File to a temp table with a XML Datatype using the below code

```
   INSERT
   INTO import.XMLCompanyDetail
     (
     XMLData
     )

   SELECT BulkColumn AS XMLData
   FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\Server\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\ExampleXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
```

However what I'm struggling to do is only import part of the data, please see below for example XML. Ideally I would want to select either CoNum 123 or CoNum 233 and get the rest of the data in that element. Although I assume that would mean somehow then getting the relvent Row num and working from there.

```
<VN>
  <CompanyList>
    <Row num="1">
      <CoNum>123</CoNum>
      <CoName>Comp1</CoName>
      <DInc>1950-01-06</DInc>
    </Row>
    <Row num="2">
      <CoNum>233</CoNum>
      <CoName>Comp2</CoName>
      <DInc>1955-11-10</DInc>
      <DDis />
    </Row>
  </CompanyList>
</VN>
```

if anyone can throw some syntax this way or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Also its worth pointing out that I shred the data to a table later in the process but by that point its to late so really need to strip out the rest of the data, or only select the relevent data in this query or from the import.XMLCompanyDetail table.

UPDATE 1 : Have found this link http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/xml-data-modification-language-workbench/ which should help.

UPDATE 2: I eventually coded the below, possibly not the most elegant but it seems to work. Spent a good ten mins trying to pass the variable in through a parameter of sp_executeSQL but couldn't get it to work so just knocked out the below...will add QUOTENAME at some point before live.

```
                        SET @SQL = 
                                N'                                      
                                UPDATE  import.XMLCompanyDetail
                                SET     XMLData.modify(''delete (//VN/CompanyList/Row[@num != ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@RowNum) + '])'')
                                '

                        EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL   @SQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see update 2.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT
    cd.ID, -- or something
    CL.Row.value('(CoNum)[1]', 'int') AS 'CoNum',
    CL.Row.value('(CoName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'CoName',
    CL.Row.value('(DInc)[1]', 'datetime') AS 'DInc'
FROM
    import.XMLCompanyDetail cd
CROSS APPLY
    cd.XMLData.nodes('/VN/CompanyList/Row') CL(ROW)
WHERE
    CL.Row.value('(@num)', 'int') = 1
```

Basically, you create a "pseudo-table" `CL.ROW` from the list of `/VN/CompanyList/Row` entries in your XML, and you then XQuery that pseudo-table for the relevant info you're interested in.

Comment: cheers for the reply, thats basically the syntax I use later in the process. Basically the above code is in my SP and then multiple other SPs use your above code to shred various values out to other tables. So I really need to either only select the CONum, COname and DIC for the specified COnum. Or select all data into import.XMLCompanyDetail and delete all other information relating to any CONum that hasn't been specified. Unfortuantley I wont know the RowNumber when i'm running my example import, only the CONum, many thanks again.